# Where can I get Offfice 365 Microsoft Store version not the Click-to-Run?

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, windows-store-app, microsoft-store

We had developed a VSTO add-in for PowerPoint. So far (From 2007 - Present) our users are able to install our add-in on traditional MSI base Office (2010,2013,2016) and the Office 365 with Click-to-Run based installation technology on both 64bit and 32bit versions.

But recently Microsoft has started to push a new version of Office which comes preinstalled with some Dell and Surface laptops and on this version our add-ins fails to install. The reason as you can see in this Knowledge Base article from Dell is that this [Office comes as a Microsoft Store Application](https://www.dell.com/support/article/pk/en/pkbsd1/sln309631/microsoft-office-2016-is-now-installed-by-default-as-a-microsoft-store-application?lang=en). Some Office add-in vendors are [recommending](https://support.jetglobal.com/hc/en-us/articles/360010895093-Excel-add-in-not-available-during-installation) to remove this and use the Clik to Run version. Here Andrei Smolin from Add-in Express [mentions some problems](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2019/02/27/office-from-store-issues/) with this Store version of Office.

I know that this version of Office is not completely built from scratch and it will [eventually support VSTO add-ins](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/faq-office-on-windows-10-in-s-mode-717193b5-ff9f-4388-84c0-277ddf07fe3f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#OfficeWinStorePlans=Office_for_home). I need this version of Office for my development environment so I can make the software ready for upcoming changes. I've tried to find this new Office 365 Microsoft Store version but I ended up getting another Click-to-Run based office even from the Microsoft Store app.

How can we get this Microsoft Store version of Office without buying a new Laptop?

Office 365 Microsft Store Version Screenshot:
[image: Office 365 Microsft Store Version Screenshot]

Comment: Did you mean you want to install MSI version Office 365? If yes, Office 365 can only be installed by Click-to-run version.

Comment: No, I know MSI version is not for Office 365, but there is this new version (Microsoft Store) please see the image attached which I'm looking for.

Comment: Perhaps your add-ins are failing because the Office installation is 64-bit. In any case, your question may be suffering from the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/271445).

Comment: Thanks, @TwistyImpersonator for your recommendation, I can see this is not a forum where I should be asking my programming problems right? So XY Problem should not be the case here but still, it is happening so I've updated my question to avoid confusions. I know the [problem](https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/264636-general/suggestions/35176501-office-365-store-version-does-not-recognize-excel) I just don't have the office version to inspect it closely and prepare a fix for it.

Comment: The “app” version is probably just a regular Click-to-Run version packages as an app. It will still be subject to additional restrictions. Also, I only see Home/Personal on the Store.

Comment: Yes, @DanielB that's what I suspect too because it supports almost all the other features but not some, most probably due to UWP sandboxing.

Comment: The best way to get help here with your problem is to tell us about the *problem* you're experiencing (can't install add-ins) and let those posting answers decide whether it's because of the version of Office you have and what to do about it.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator, I'm happy for your support as I'm new here. Yes, the main goal I've is to get the add-in working on Store version of Office but installation is not the only problem. I'm asking for the Office version source because even If I'm able to fix installation, I know there will be some other problems too.

Comment: Asking for the source of that software is not on-topic and will cause your question to be closed.

Comment: Why is asking for the source of this software is off-topic? I'm not asking for an illegal copy or something like that. The software is required to set up the **add-in development environment**. Anyways I've found it myself and added an answer for anyone else who might need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of finding, I was finally able to get the programs using the [Office app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/office/9wzdncrd29v9?activetab=pivot:overviewtab).

Here is the about page screenshot of the app.

[image: about page screenshot]

You can install the Click to Run version by going to **My account** tab. And finally, if you need the Office 365 Microsoft store apps go to **Programs** tab and install the required office apps (Word, PowerPoint) from the Office 365 programs category.

Here is a screenshot for that.

[image: screenshot]

Please note that the latest Office app does not include these tabs on my other PC so it might not be available for you as well. I was able to get this version from a Dell OS Recovery Image.