# How to open a file in Word

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I want to tell Windows 10 to edit an HTML file in MS Word (I have Office 365). I right-click and select "open with..." but do not see Word. I click "Choose another app" but still do not see Word. I click "More apps..." but still do not see Word. I click "Look for another app on this computer", and then I see the files on my computer, but I have no idea where Word is. It is not in "Program Files" nor in "Program Files x86". 
Where is it? How can I find it?

EDIT: I do not have any folder called "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office". I looked for "winword" on my file system, and here is what I found:

[image]

A file called "winword.exe" exists only here:

[image]

As you can see, it has a size of 0, but when I click it, Word opens as usual.

However, when I click it in the "Open With..." dialog, I get an error:

[image]

Comment: Do you have Office 2016 installed?  If so, uninstall it, restart, and then install Office again. Word is definitely available in More apps so what you want can be done

Comment: Do you have a shortcut to Word somewhere? Start up word, then go to task manager, find `winword.exe` under details, right click and select "open file location". Where does that lead?

Comment: It leads to "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Office.Desktop.Word_16051.12130.20272.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Office16".  Thanks for the advice on how to find the location of a running program - this is just what I needed!

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi glad to hear you found it. Did you by any chance install office using the windows store? I'll update my answer accordingly if that's the case

Comment: The reason you do not have a Microsoft Office folder within Program Files is due to the fact Office was installed through the Microsoft Store. [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1413880/where-can-i-get-offfice-365-microsoft-store-version-not-the-click-to-run) is how you install the correct version to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default location of the MS Office executables, including Word, is in one of the following paths:

<sup>If installed using the default installer from office.com:</sup>
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16`

<sup>If installed using the Microsoft Store:</sup>
`C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Office.Desktop.xxxxx\Office16` where `xxxxx` is version-dependent.

You should be able to find Word here as `WINWORD.EXE`. Selecting this in the 'open with' window should work.

You can also find the executable's location by right-clicking on an existing shortcut and selecting "open file location". The same can be done on running processes using the task manager.

Comment: I do not have this folder! See my edit

Comment: @Ramhound Done, though I couldn't verify the MS Store path myself - I run off the default installer. I do remember that the numbers in the path aren't static though